# Bash is default, yet still changes when I run "bash: in terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

When I open the terminal, the prompt is as follows:

```
<computer-name>:~ <username>$
```

When I run `bash` in the Mac terminal, it changes my prompt to the following of course:

```
bash-3.2$
```

However, this surprises me, because my shell is already bash:  I know this because when I run the following echo command it yields bash:

```
echo $SHELL 
/bin/bash
```

So, why does the prompt change, when bash is already my default?  Is there something I'm misunderstanding here?  Thank you.

Comment: What is returned by `echo $PS1` before and after running `bash` ?

Comment: `/bin/bash` is version 3.2 in Mac OS X; is your terminal configured to run a different `bash` that's not in your path on startup?

Comment: Try `bash -l`; that will run it as a login shell, and it should give you your normal prompt.

Comment: So,  `echo $PS1` prints `\h:W \u\$`  when using `<computer-name>:~ <username>$`, and it prints `\s-\v\$` when using `bash`.  What, if anything, does this tell us?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Prompt is defined by PS1 variable. See

```
echo $PS1
```

in both cases.
Most likely when you login, some of start scripts change the value of `PS1`. Inspect files:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

For more information how bash starts, see [INVOCATION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc6) section in `man bash` and for `PS1` and others prompt related variables see [PARAMETERS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc12) section.

Answer (score 0):

Your PROMPT (aka PS1) changes because when you just open terminal, it, probably, run bash either:
1) as login shell (in that case bash, probably, has special settings for login shell mode (look at ~/.bash_profile or /etc/profile (although, /etc/profile should load even for non-login shells)));

2) with TERM value, different, that you have in manually called (actually, I doubt it);

3) with it's own custom bashrc or something like that;

Anyway, you can edit ~/.bashrc (for example, copy PS1 there from ~/.bash_login and get what you want)